# SOAP - using the like simple operator

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I have a working SOAP envelope to retrieve rows from a data extension.  If I change the simple operator in the filter to 'like' instead of 'equals' I get the error message: 'Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Here is the SOAP envelope:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876">
            <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Self_Service_SMS_log]</ObjectType>
            <Properties>cohorts</Properties>
            <Properties>_CustomObjectKey</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>cohorts</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>like</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>1e32cc7c-a4e0-e511-ace7-00110a66cef9</Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Hi Jimmy, could you find a answer to this question? I am at the same point now